# Entity Framework 4.1 Two Tracked Queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I am learning EF so apology if this has been answered some where else. I could not find a solution to this. I am using Two Tracked Queries because i cannot use Include as it does not support condition. So my code is as follow:

```
    List<int> CategoryIDs = _categoryIDs.Split(',').Select(t => int.Parse(t)).ToList();
```

My models:

```
 public class Genre
{

    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string iconURL{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int DisplaySequence { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; 

}



   public class Category
   {


    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
   }


     public class SubCategory
      {


    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }     
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }  
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 
}
```

Then I have my view model:

```
public class HomeIndexData
{

    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }         

}
```

Then I am trying to return viewmodel to my index:

```
     public ActionResult Index()
     {

     var genres = db.Genres.ToList().OrderBy(g => g.DisplaySequence);
     var categories = db.Categories.Include(i => i.SubCategories)
                     .Where(i => CategoryIDs.Contains(i.CategoryId));
            foreach (var category in categories)
            {

            };

           HomeIndexData viewModel = new HomeIndexData
            {
                Genres = genres                         

            };
            return View(viewModel);      

        }
```

It returns the result but I wanted to filter the SubCategories as well. How do I put WHERE condition instead of .Include(i => i.SubCategories).

Please note I dnt want to return anonymous type, that is why I am Two Tracked Queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would get much more attention if you shared your model. Does Categories and Subcategories are of the same type? In other words is this self referencing table?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have shared my models as well. Any thought on how I can put condition on subcategories?

Comment: What are you expecting to see returned?

Comment: I am expecting to see Genre, Filtered Categories and Filtered Subcategories. My code alreaady filtered the categories. Would like to do the same for the subcategories

Comment: Why not just a third line `var subCategories = db.SubCategories.Where("your SubCategory filter")...`?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for var subcategories = db.Subcategories.Where(e => CategoryIDs.Contains(e.CategoryID)); This will select you subcategories of categories that you have already filtered.

Comment: I cannot use that for Entity framework two Tracked queries

Comment: Also, did you think about using explicit loading? You can add filter there then.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think I know what you want to do here:

```
// so filter out categories
var categories = db.Categories.Where(c => CategoryIDs.Contains(c.CategoryID)); 

// so filter out subcategories - I'm not sure what kind of filtering you want on subcategories
var subcategories = db.Subcategories.Where(s => CategoryIDs.Contains(s.SubCategoryID)); 
// so alternatively just do this: var subcategories = db.Subcategories.Where(s => s.DoYourFilteringForSubcategories);

foreach (var subcategory in subcategories)
    var cat = categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CategoryID == subcategory.CategoryID)
    if (cat != null)
    {
        cat.Subcategories.Add(subcategory);
    }
    else
    {
        // very good question? what are you going to do with subcategories that
        //match your criteria, but its category does not meet category filter
    }
```

in your model you need to add:

```
   public class Category
   {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    **public virutal List<Subcategory> Subcategories{ get; set; }**
   }
```

So then you end up only with categories that match your filter and contains only subcategories that match the filter. All strongly typed and tracked.